# Writing a mod rewrite rule to redirect two URL types to a custom permalink

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I map from this format, `http://example.com/is-that-for-real/.html` (about 500 errors), to this format, `http://example.com/1045/is-that-for-real/`?

This is my current and actual permalink.

Comment: Where does the number come from?

Comment: the number is the /%post_id%/ or numer of the post . My new permalink is http://relhurg1.com/post-ID/postnam/ I have tried so many ways to get an answer that I even posted to my blog Lifejustiz® at http://relhurg1.com  today. I think I put a lot of information that may help...thank you...jong

Comment: My site is Http://relhurg1.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. But you don't need to use mod_rewrite directly to change your permalinks, you can do it in WordPress' settings. Clearly you at least somewhat understand this, since you're quoting the templates you need to use. If you have a problem after changing the permalink, like resources on the page not loading, that is a separate issue, and the mere fact the page itself loads means it's working.

Comment: Hi Crimson---can I use the templates you mentin in a 301 redirect using the /%post_id%/ and /%postname%/ I assume you use the term template for thes items???Can i put that format in a regec 301 redirect as it sure would make it understadable...jong

Comment: Hi Crimson...I started a new discussion on a similar issue..see profile question 2. I am still trying to unserstand how to work the google 404 errors. I have over 800 404 errors due to the permalink changes made and broken links as a result. My current sitemap is perfect..do I use Redirects from the google 404 page to my current urls on my site or use a rdirect scheme....I am starting to think I an shooting myself in the foot...not being able to rewrite the error urls on google...am I right? If you could would you write me proper RedirectMatch Permanent for this issue? Thank you, Jackg